# Android widget max allowed size

Tags: android, android-widget

We can set the MINIMUM size of a widget using e.g.

```
android:minHeight="40dp"
android:minResizeHeight="40dp"
android:minResizeWidth="40dp"
android:minWidth="40dp"
```

There are no `android:max___` properties.

**Is there a way to limit the MAXIMUM size of a resizeable widget?**

(perhaps a resize callback I'm not seeing or something like that?)

---

Noting that the docs say a common use case for resizing is lists or grids. Which require no setting of a max size.

My use case is simply "*client asked for a single widget that is either 1x1 or 2x2*". Will he get what he wants, or will I have to change his mind for him?

Answer (score 9):

> Is there a way to limit the MAXIMUM size of a resizeable widget?

**NO**, but you can limit the user by disable the horizontal or vertical re-sizing in the `XML` file of your widget.

**Example: for only Horizontal**

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_layout"
android:minHeight="220dp"
android:minWidth="180dp"
android:resizeMode="horizontal"
android:updatePeriodMillis="0" 
android:previewImage="@drawable/widget_all_in_one_preview"/>
```

**Example: for only Vertical**

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_layout"
android:minHeight="220dp"
android:minWidth="180dp"
android:resizeMode="vertical"
android:updatePeriodMillis="0" 
android:previewImage="@drawable/widget_all_in_one_preview"/>
```

**You can also do both by:**

```
android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"
```

Make sure you are using `NinePatch` images or setting the `Background` color programatically.

**OR** provide a fixed size `Widget` to be in the safe side :)

I hope it helps

Comment: client did not want 2 different fixed size widgets... time to change his mind.

Answer (score 2):

Few years late but, maybe doing a second layout where if user crosses a max width/height, the widget will switch to this layout and no longer grow in size to match_parent.

Using a Layout with the predefined max height/width, with the addition of nesting inside a frame layout if you want to control where it sits inside it's bounding area.

Answer (score 1):

As @Sami Eltamawy said you can't set maximum height. but you can set at widget layout:
layout_height="wrap_content".

With this way, widget size will be limited with your content.

I know that it won't help to OP but it can help others